# Given a positive integer, n, how can a numerical triangle of height n-1 be printed?

Tags: python, for-loop

- [HackerRank: Triangle Quest](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-quest-1/problem)
- Using only arithmetic operations, a single `for-loop`, and a single `print` statement.
- String operations are not permitted.
- Constraints `1 ≤ n ≤ 9`
- As an example, given `n=5` as input, print the following output:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

Comment: Why are there so many constraints? Just curious.

Comment: @ssundarraj it is a problem from [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-quest-1).  That's why there are some constraints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using math, it would be,

### Python 2.7:

```
for i in range(1,n):
    print i*(10**i-1)/9
```

Check [repdigit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit) for more information.

### Python 3+

- Leave or remove `int` depending if you want `.0` or not.

```py
for i in range(1, n):
    print(int(i*(10**i-1)/9))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify no newline at the print statement. In python 2, that means using `sys.stdout.write` or importing the python3 `print` function

```
from __future__ import print_function # python 2 only
def expand(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for _ in range(i):
            print(i, end="")
        print(" ", end="")
    print("")


expand(5)
1 22 333 4444 55555
```

After more details were posted, and a link to the original question on hackerrank, I realize this is not actually a valid solution. Still, I will leave it here in case it is helpful.

Comment: @Falko I don't see how that would be usable in this example. Try it.